# heroku http streaming (sse) disconnect not detected with express.js

Tags: heroku, express, server-sent-events

Heroku is not detecting when a client disconnects.

I cloned their starter [app](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample) and added a couple lines for sse:

```
var sse = require('connect-sse')();

app.get('/testing', sse, function(req, res, next) {
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      var date;
      date = new Date();
      res.json({
        ping: date
      });
      return console.log(date);
    }, 2000);
    return req.on('close', function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return console.log("cleared");
    });
 });
```

When I go to my [app](http://fathomless-castle-6301.herokuapp.com/testing) I see the correct reponse:

```
id: 0
data: {"ping":"2014-01-05T23:53:49.835Z"}

id: 1
data: {"ping":"2014-01-05T23:53:51.839Z"}
```

But after I close the browser tab heroku does not register that I did.

With `heroku logs -t` I keep getting the date printed out and never `cleared`

This works locally with `foreman start` but not on heroku.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for the [connect-sse node module](https://github.com/superjoe30/connect-sse), it looks like you should be referring to the `sse` middleware **without** parentheses, like so:

```
app.get('/testing', sse, function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I made those changes but am seeing the same thing on heroku. This works locally with `foreman start`, but not on heroku.